# A modified version of Goursat's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open with $T\subset \Omega$ a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$. Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ except possibly at a point $w\in T$. If $f$ is bounded near $w$ then show that $$\int_T f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0$$

This is a problem from Shakarchi and Stein. What I tried was consider the disc, inside $T$, centered at $w$ inside which $|f|\le M$ say. Consider a triangle $T^*$ contained inside that disc. Now joining the vertices of $T$ and $T^*$ we get some new triangles in whose interior $f$ is holomorphic, hence Goursat's Theorem can be applied. But now I have to prove that for $T^*$, where $f$ is bounded. I can't do this part. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is bounded near $\omega$ implies that $f$ can be extended in a holomorphic function in $\Omega$, so the residue of the resulting function at $\omega$ is zero like the value of the integral $\int_Tf$.